# Outlook error-'Can't open e-mail folders.You must connect to Exchange w/ current profile before you can sync folders w/ your Outlook data file'

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2010

*Note that the error message I put in the title of this question is abbreviated.  The actual error message is below.*

I have an Exchange account and using Outlook 2010 as the client.  I run in Cached Exchange Mode and have an .OST file locally.

Recently I uninstalled and reinstalled office.  I set up a new mail profile when prompted by Outlook 2010 upon first execution of the program.  In my initial attempt, I pointed the data file at my existing OST file.  In my second attempt, I had Outlook create a fresh empty file.

In both cases I'm getting the error 'Cannot open your default e-mail folders.  You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronize your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost).', also shown in this screenshot --> http://drop.io/4rc9v9o/asset/outlook-error-png.

I don't know how to connect with the current profile - that's what I thought I did when I created a new .OST file?

I've had this problem for several days so my OST file is now out of date.  Once I get things running I obviously want my active mailbox to update the OST, not the other way around.

Comment: In my case a repair install of Office fixed this; deleting .osts or even a completely clean user account didn't work. I suspect a bad Outlook patch then; annoyingly you can't roll back patches if you've installed Outlook through Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was an Exchange-side problem.  Support told me that for some reason, MAPI was disabled on my account.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as it answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same exact message after we disabled and re-enabled services on a user mailbox, which also include their mailbox quotas.

To get the user back online, we had to push an active directory site to site replication.
After this was done, the user was good to go.

Answer (score 1):

We found a weird solution to this issue. We have the user open up OWA from their local machine on our LAN, and then open up outlook. Not sure what the correlation was but when we run into this issue, opening both up always seems to fix it. It must be something that gets messed up on Exchange but it seems to clear once the user opens OWA and then opens up Outlook.  We are currently on Exchange 2003 and Outlook 2007

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround from [this blog](http://insomniacgeek.com/cannot-open-your-default-e-mail-folders-you-must-connect-to-microsoft-exchange-with-the-current-profile-before-you-can-synchronize-your-folders-with-your-offline-folder-file/). It resolved the issue for me.

You should enable 'Always prompt for login credentials' in your Exchange account's security settings. To edit your account settings without opening Outlook go to Control Panel, Mail.

Comment: Answers are generally recommend to contain some actual information instead of linking directly to the reference, perhaps try explaining the solution instead of just linking to it in the future. :)

Comment: mainly when the blog acount was suspended :)

Answer (score 0):

Same error message here. Happened when we ran out of licenses when re-activating a user.

We needed to buy the additional license, then remove(!) any license for this user and add a license again. Ensure there is a primary email/mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I just stumbled onto this issue and spent the last two hours tinkering with settings.  I knew it was not server-side because Outlook works fine on another computer.

The following solution worked for me, so thought I might share it in hope that it will save someone else time.

1. Click on Start
2. Go to Control Panel
3. Click on Mail
4. Click on Email Account
5. Double-click on the email account
6. Click on More Settings
7. Change to the Connection tab
8. Check the Connect to Microsoft Exchange using HTTP box
9. Click on the Microsoft Exchange Proxy Setting box
10. Put your server's owa web address into the http:// box
11. Change authentication method to Basic Authentication
12. Click OK
13. Change to Security tab
14. Check "Encrypt Data..." and "Always Ask For Credentials" (this can be unchecked again after first login)

Answer (score -2):

Please see this tutorial.It is for you all.

http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2015/11/solved-%EF%BB%BFcannot-start-microsoft-outlook-cannot-open-the-outlook-windows-the-set-of-folders-cannot-be-opened-you-must-connect-to-microsoft-exchange-with-the-current-profile-before-you-can-s.html

Comment: All answers in this site must be self-contained because otherwise, they are worthless in the event of a link rot.